# Thermal Fuse Crimp material

Tags: fuses, thermal

I speculate this is just barely an EE question, but I'll risk it anyway:

I'm replacing a set of 175C 10A thermal fuses (with 172C 10A actually).  At this temperature / current range, do we need special high-temp crimps or will any ol' ebay copper crimps do?

EDIT: Good comments, some clarifications:

- application is an electric single-burner mini stovetop
- stovetop wire insulation is in excellent shape and will shroud crimps
- crimp material suggestions welcome and appreciated

Comment: Since portions of the terminal are un-insulated anyway, you could just use fully un-insulated terminals and not worry about it.  They might be cheaper as well.

Comment: Presumably you are protecting something important against over-temperature. The something important situation is not one to use anything "Any old eBay crap", but a situation to use the right materials and tools, such that you know by the manufacturers specifications of your crimp connections that everything will hold under all of the stresses; electrical, mechanical or thermal and avoid unwanted breaks, shorts or other failures.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I've added some clarifications

Comment: Can you not buy the crimps at a hardware store or electrician supply house near you?

Comment: @mkeith possibly.  As long as I don't burn the house down with the stuff I buy lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copper being soft metal,  may or may not be poor crimp material for this application.  Some are silver plated brass, , stainless steel, some copper. It depends on the mating materials , ruggedness, operating conditions and tooling.

It MUST be  capable of a 5 pound pull test without fatique on resistance or strength.  It must  be a gas tight fitting, so that the mating surfaces do not oxidize and must be done with proper tooling for consistency.

Commercial equipment may use a spot welder but a high quality gas-tight crimp machine is cheaper.  There are many material types depending on other specs which were not given in the question, such as budget,qty.  & reliability.

[image]

Comment: Wow, intense!  I'm just a cheap guy trying to help out my cheap friend and fix the little stove for as few bucks as possible.  Was hoping for a budget of $10 but if that's not viable in a safe way, abort! abort!

Comment: you might learn the intense details of the perfect crimp or fail miserably

Comment: The cost can be pennies with the right crimp tool